# Changed GPU from AMD to RTX - color space issue

Tags: gpu, color, color-management

I changed GPU from Vega64 to RTX 2070SU, and clean installed Windows 10. 
My issue is about different colors in Blender (screenshot shows my problem).
[image]
In other software I have untouched colors/gamma, I really have no idea where is the problem. :(
(Already tried to change some settings in Control Panel of NVIDIA with no results)

edit: 
I forgot to add information about version of Blender - that is Blender 2.83 BETA. 
I tried to replicate it in Blender 2.82 - PROBLEM IS NOT THERE ANYMORE
edit2:  It's common problem of this experimental build.
https://developer.blender.org/T75750

Comment: I forgot to add information about version of Blender - that is Blender 2.83 BETA.
I tried to replicate it in Blender 2.82 - PROBLEM IS NOT THERE ANYMORE

Comment: If you need to add more information you can use the [edit] link below your question. Also please make the title of your question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.